# Jest mocked implementation not being called outside of test function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a 3rd party module I need to mock (moment.js).  I want to set the implementation to the default implementation before requiring the file I'm testing.  The only function I'm mocking is the default export of the module, so I assign the prototype and static members to those of the actual implementation, as well.

**season.js**

```js
import moment from 'moment';

export var currentSeason = getCurrentSeason();

export function currentSeasion() {
    const diff = moment().diff(/* ... */);
    // ...

    return /* a number */;
}
```

**__tests__/season.js**

```js
import moment from 'moment';

jest.mock('moment');
const actualMoment = jest.requireActual('moment');

moment.mockImplementation((...args) => actualMoment(...args));
Object.assign(moment, actualMoment);

const { getCurrentSeason } = require('../season');

test('getCurrentSeason()', () => {
    moment.mockReturnValue(actualMoment(/* ... */));
    expect(getCurrentSeason()).toBe(1);
});
```

I confirmed via debugging that `mockImpelementation()` is being called correctly, and within the test, it's being called correctly too.  However, in the initialization of `currentSeason`, `moment()` is returning undefined.  When I stepped into the `moment()` mocked function, `mockConfig.mockImpl` is `undefined`.

Running `expect(moment()).toBeUndefined()` in the test file but outside of any test before the import of season.js runs the mock implementation, as well.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's only not working in the initialization of `currentSeason`.

Comment: I think I'm hitting a similar problem...is this a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430951 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how useful this will be for anyone else, but my solution turned out to be to pull my mock code into it's own `/__mocks__/moment.js` file.

```js
const actual = jest.requireActual('moment'),
    moment = jest.fn((...args) => actual(...args));

export default Object.assign(moment, actual);
```